# Manipulate View from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

Good morning, thanks in advance for answering.

My view implements a pan & zoom library: [A WPF Custom Control for Zooming and Panning](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning)

In the View, there is a control to zoom to a Point based on a mouse double click:

```
private void zoomAndPanControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == 0)
   {
      Point doubleClickPoint = e.GetPosition(content);
      zoomAndPanControl.AnimatedSnapTo(doubleClickPoint);
   }
}
```

I would like to force "zoomAndPanControl.**AnimatedSnapTo**(doubleClickPoint);" to a particular Point based on ViewModel data for a geometry point that I draw, when I pull it. So, that the view will pan to the point of the new geometry x,y coords.  The geometry/points are already bound to the view.

As an added note, pulling data for the geometry point is happening in a DispatchTimer.  As the new geometry coords are read, I'd like the view to pan & follow these coords.

Is there an easy way to access this control from the ViewModel, when I get data?  Possibly simulate a mouse event with a custom point?  I'm not sure the best way to go about it.

Comment: Firstly - your ViewModel and View, in true MVVM should never meet and know nothing of each other. So telling your view to do something from data in your view model requires a binding or datatrigger. The easiest thing to me looking at what you have shown, is to create a dependency property in your ZoomAndPanControl, which when set, causes the behaviour you're after (calls AnimatedSnapTo) - that property can then be bound to your view model. Change your view model property and the binding will trigger the action.

Comment: @kidshaw That isn't true. The view will hold a reference to the viewModel. That's the only way you're ever going to get databinding to work. The view will inevitably know about a viewmodel. The viewmodel should never know about its user.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Add dependency property to the ZoomAndPanControl library, so I can bind. I was hoping for a simpler solution, as the control is already available to the view... but it is what it is I guess.

Comment: @Shoe - yes, I overstated the separation there. I tend to implement View Model Locator pattern so am used to thinking of them being separated via interface - you are correct.

Comment: I'll post my suggestion as an answer, in case it works for you.

Comment: Is `content` what resides on the ViewModel?

Comment: No, content is part of the library/custom control that references the child object's size/width etc... So that it's possible to pan to a particular point on a canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually handle these kind of scenarios is by defining a delegate on the ViewModel, set it in the View, and invoke it when needed:

Define a method in your ViewModel that takes in an `Action<Point>` and a `Point` object for current mouse position:

```
public void ExecuteAnimatedSnapTo(Action<Point> animatedSnapToAction, Point pointerPosition)
{
    if (animatedSnapToAction != null && pointerPosition != null)
    {
        // Create a new point based on the one passed in and data in ViewModel
        Point newPoint =
            new Point(pointerPosition.X + viewModelData.X, pointerPosition.Y + viewModelData.Y);

        // Invoke the delegate using the new point
        animatedSnapToAction(newPoint);
    }
}
```

Then in your View's code behind, execute this method:

```
private void zoomAndPanControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == 0)
   {
      Point doubleClickPoint = e.GetPosition(content);

      var viewModel = (MyViewModel)this.DataContext;

      viewModel.ExecuteAnimatedSnapTo(zoomAndPanControl.AnimatedSnapTo, doubleClickPoint);
   }
}
```

With this approach, you're still preserving the isolation of the View from the ViewModel. When [unit] testing the VM, the delegate and the point will probably be null when passed into the method. The `if` block then prevents the "UI" logic from being tested.

One thing you need to be careful about is if the ViewModel data is calculated on a different thread, you HAVE TO execute the delegate on the UI dispatcher.

### Edit

I was under the impression that the ViewModel had all the data needed to invoke the delegate when `MouseDoubleClick` gets fired. If that's not the case, a better solution would be to expose the `Action` as a property on VM and call it when needed:

```
public Action<Point> AnimatedSnapToAction { get; set; }
```

When you create an instance of the VM on the View, set the property as well:

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.AnimatedSnapToAction = zoomAndPanControl.AnimatedSnapTo;

    this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Now you can execute the delegate on the VM whenever needed. For example, if it needs to be called on a `DispatcherTimer`'s tick, it would look like this:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Calculate geometry data

    if(AnimatedToSnapAction != null)
    {
        AnimatedSnapToAction(pointCalculatedUsingGeometryData);
    }
}
```

Comment: That interesting, I'm still wrapping my head around it.  As far as I can tell, in this example the double click is driving "AnimatedSnapTo."  I'm looking to call the "AnimatedSnapTo" when the viewmodel gets new data for a geometry point (which is bound in the view).  So that I can pan to the new location of the point.

Comment: This WILL call `AnimatedSnapTo` on the ViewModel. Your View needs data from the ViewModel before it can call `zoomAndPanControl.AnimatedSnapTo()`. On the other hand, you don't want to expose the entire control or the View to the ViewModel. What's happening here is the `ExecuteAnimatedSnapTo` method takes in a "callback" action which, in this case, happens to point to "something" on the UI. The VM doesn't know or care what the `Action` is or where it comes from, it just calls it; and that's the whole beauty of it since you're not breaking the isolation between the View and ViewModel.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. I assumed when MouseDoubleClick is fired, the VM already has the extra data it needs to create a new point. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, it's an interesting solution, but I don't think it will work in my case.  The data is coming from a DispatchTimer on the ViewModel, which sets the geometry object's x/y, and is bound in the view.  So, logically the `AnimatedSnapTo` would be called after pulling the data, so the view can pan & follow this point.

Comment: Then in that case, you can expose the `Action` as a property and call it whenever needed. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To control you View via binding, your control needs something to bind to.

1. Add an Dependency Property to your custom control that accepts a 'Point' type.
2. Bind a property with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented from your view model to that DP - note, a ValueConverter can be added in here should you want to refrain from using the 'Point' class in your VM.
3. In the definition of your DP, adapt the setter to trigger your AnimatedSnapTo(...) method

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A view model should expose the data and behaviour that your view needs to display and interact, it should never have a reference to the View itself.

The View implicitly or explicitly has a reference to the ViewModel.  Via this reference you can either call methods, bind data, hook up events, etc...

To keep it simple in this case you probably want to execute a command on your ViewModel when the user double clicks on the control and then any public properties exposed by the ViewModel can be modified in the command execution.  These properties can then be used to determine the point you want to zoom to.

Comment: That's my dilemma, I want to use "AnimatedSnapTo" in a custom way.  The double clicking works fine, in the view, as it's a view control.  But I'm drawing shapes on a canvas with binding from the viewmodel, and It'd like to force this "AnimatedSnapTo" to the position of the shape.

Comment: What does your ViewModel actually represent apart from just shapes?

Comment: The viewmodel holds the data for the shapes, i.e. x/y coords, name, etc.. They are bound to the view, displayed on a canvas.  I'm trying to pan to those x/y coords when they are added.